# No Unity (desktop/sidebar) after uninstalling bluez

Tags: unity, compiz

Had some problems with bluetooth earlier so I wanted to reinstall the bluetooth component. I used `apt-get remove/install bluez`.

It looked like it uninstalled a lot of stuff. (Uninstalling took a lot longer than installing bluez). After reboot I got to the login screen (and my bluetooth-mouse working!), but after login I see my desktop and icons but no unity/sidebar etc.

I tried compizconfig as many suggested in similar help threads but I don even have the unity plugin showing in compiz so i cant reenable it. I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu-desktop package as well as unity (using apt-get) but at no help. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: user309668: Make sure you have the `unity-control-center` and `unity-control-center-signon` packages. Also make sure you reboot.

Comment: Another thing that could be tried could be `sudo apt-get install unity*` - note this will likly install loads of rubbish like the web applications etc, but these can be removed later.

Comment: Unity-control-center and ...-signon was already installed. Unity* doesnt work at all, gives the error "unable to correct problems, you Held broken packages" after showing some conflicts with variants of unity-scope-... (Although not sure this is the cause since they install fine seperatly).

Comment: I successfully installed gnome which works fine, I could at least log in to gnome shell and save my personal files. I still however have no luck of getting unity to work/load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu, nothing else seemed to work. At least a  tip can be to go into terminal (ctrl+alt+f1) and install gnome (followed these instructions http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-gnome-shell-desktop-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts.html). Then log into gnome desktop and save your files (or even use it, everything seemed to work fine).

An even better tip would be to never run the command "sudo apt-get remove bluez" since it seems to break unity beyond repair (at least for someone with my limited knowledge).